# What's wrong with having a reference member in C++?

Tags: c++

While reading "C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices" I came across the following:

> Note that using a reference or `auto_ptr` member is almost always wrong.

However, the text doesn't elaborate on why this should be wrong. So what is so wrong about having a class with reference members?

Comment: With `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` available, using `auto_ptr` is **always** wrong in **any** context. It was dodgy enough before the other `_ptr`s were standardized, and it's now deprecated. Of course this book was written long before they were available.

Comment: If a reference is wrong, then so must be an immutable (raw) pointer. Why is that not mentioned?

Comment: If you have a pointer/reference as a member it means that the state of your object is dependent on state outside of it's control. Sometimes you need this, but then I would recommend to always accept that dependency in the constructor so you can test it with a mock for that dependency.

Comment: This is a fine example of why it's so hard to "be a productive C++ programmer" simply by following a shopping list of recipes. There's no way around knowing the language at least a little bit and making your own decision. *Usually* C++ wants to be value-based and objects should exist and be consistent independent of context. But that idea has limitations, and sometimes you do need one class to rely on some contextual (lifetime) guarantees, and when you need that, you really need that. It shouldn't be the default approach, but neither is it generally wrong. It just depends.

Answer (score 1):

I think the text is telling you to avoid embedding in a class anything whose existence is out of the control of that class. References and auto pointers may refer to already deleted objects.

Answer (score 0):

One problem might be that references are immutable, once set they can't be changed.. Another problem might be dangling references, where you have a reference to now destroyed object.

Answer (score 0):

A reference member can never be changed, rendering the class non-assignable. The same goes for members of `const` object type. Also, the best practice is to set any invalidated reference to `nullptr`, but that cannot be applied.

Simply use a pointer instead. There is also `std::reference_wrapper` for the cases where a bare pointer really won't do.

`auto_ptr` is long obsolete and deprecated, so that simply shouldn't come up. It had wonky copy semantics.